# Random freezing on UbuntuGNOME 15.10

Tags: gnome, 15.10, freeze

I have a machine with a new installation of UbuntuGNOME 15.10 (64-bit), which has, in the last two days, frozen completely few times.

By frozen, I mean that the desktop becomes completely unresponsive and unchanging. I have no luck trying to switch to a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), and have to shutoff and restart my computer to fix.

Though there isn't really a definitive task that my computer is doing when this happens, it has happened sometimes while watching a video on YouTube or locally, although many times I am not watching a video when this happens. Also, memory and CPU usage are normal when it freezes.

I believe this problem has some ties with my hard drive, because when Ubuntu is booting following when it freezes, it shows a message that it is cleaning orphaned inodes.

**Edit**

I probably should also add that my home directory is encrypted with `ecryptfs` after I selected 'Encrypt My Home Directory' during installation, thought I doubt that has anything to do with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will be of much help, but when I stumble on this kind of problem (screen freezing), I try to update nvidia, and if it is not enough, I remove the graphic card and remove the dust on it. That helped me a few times.

I remember though that none of these methods solved my problem on Ubuntu 15.10, and I finally downgraded to 15.04 or 14.04 because I could not figure out why. I also changed my computer a few weeks later, and perhaps it is also computer related - I haven't tried Ubuntu 15.10 with this new computer however to figure it out.

Comment: Although my computer doesn't have a graphics card, I'll try to find drivers for my Intel processor.